# copy all data from a table in Linq database in WCF and pass them for another program

Tags: c#, linq, wcf

I have a WCF class library that Contains a Linq Database with a table "users".  I also have a `WindowFormApplication` Project in same namespace.

There is a `DataGridView` in my project that should show the Users table.

How can I pass this table to my project?

Comment: generate a proxy class using `Svcutil.exe` or `Add Service Reference` in the forms application,call the `WCF Service` operation to fetch the data,bind it with the gridview.

Comment: You can't add a service reference to a WCF Class Library.  The class library needs to be hosted somehow, and you can add a reference to the hosted service.  Alternatively, if you don't need the WCF functionality, just consume the WCF Class library directly in your Forms application.